# CodeIgniter Email from required - any way use server default user@host.myservername.com

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email

With the latest DMARC restrictions, we have run into problems using codeigniter for sending mail FROM the user submitting a form or FROM say gmail/yahoo etc (any third party non-server email address).

Obviously, the solution is to set the form to send FROM the me@mydomain.com (where mydomain.com is the domain on the server), however, with the current configuration/use of this custom CMS, this email must be defined dynamically.

Is it possible, within the code igniter framework, to allow the FROM to default to the server send mail (IE something like user@host.myservername.com)?

I have tried to leave from blank and removing it altogether, not in the library but a simple form handler function, to no avail.

Any thoughts on this much appreciated!

EDIT: Code Snippet

```
    public function send_form($id)
{
    log_message('error', 'id - ' . $id);

        $this->load->library('email');

        $emailMsg = '';
        $fromEmail='';

        foreach($this->input->post() as $key => $value)
        {
        //gets values etc 
            }


        $domainEmail=$query->get_send;

   $this->email->to($domainEmail);

            $this->email->from($domainEmail);


            $this->email->reply_to($fromEmail);


        $this->email->subject('Contact Form');
        $this->email->message($emailMsg);


        if ($this->email->send())
        {
        $didSend=true;
        }

    if ($didSend != true)
        {
            echo 'email send failed';

        }
}
```

The for each that I had to comment out the code, gets the $fromEmail (which is the form submitters email). The domain email is dynamic (the user can fill this in) and is currently set as where to send the email and also where the email is from. I would like to see the TO remain as dynamic and then FROM be defaulted from the server. I hope that makes sense. I know if you do a "malformed" php mail header/from it defaults to the server user email but hoping for a codeigniter solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Definetly possible, if you can show the relevant code, eg the model that sends the email

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help.

Set the config right after load email library.

```
$this->email->initialize('email_noreply');
```

And remove the form attribute

```
$this->email->from
```

Tested CI Version : 2.1.3

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I received several php errors .. I removed the from in the function and added the initialize part. 



Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 67


Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 614

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 380

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1080

Comment: This error not lieu of code i provide, this is foreach loop error. the arguments you passing might be not an array.

Comment: or might that can be due to CI vesion. check you version.

Comment: Thank you.. The only library that matters really in this case the EMAIL, correct?  Are there any other libraries/helpers that I should be looking at here?

Comment: I have upgraded completely to 2.2.0 and made appropriate changes. I simply get my failed message if I use the code provided. If I set the from, it works and I receive the message so the send mail is still working/no code errors. Any other thoughts? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let me figure out your real current working environment. are you using smtp? 
Because im using smtp from sendgrid.net and with protocol smtp.

Comment: I am not using smtp, using the mail protocol. Using smtp will not work in my situation ..

Answer (score 0):

try this one and bingo

```
                            $message = 'you message;
                            $email = $email;
                            $this->load->library('email');
                            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
                            $config['smtp_port']='465';
                            $config['smtp_timeout']='30';
                            $config['charset']='utf-8';
                            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
                            $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
                            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
                            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
                            $this->email->initialize($config);
                            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                            $subject = 'you subject';
                            $this->email->from('noreply@noreply.com');
                            $this->email->to($email);
                            $this->email->subject($subject);
                            $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 
                            // Email Data
                            $c_items = '';
                            mail($email,"My subject",$message);
                            // Sending Email
                            $this->email->message($message);
                           $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I wanted to use an actual email address not a noreply@noreply.com. Wouldn't this come across as a potential phishing/spam as well? After all, I am making up an address that is not on my domain .. Or is this noreply domain generally recognized as ok to use as a default?

Comment: you can replace that one with orignal

Comment: Thank you for trying! It has to have the ability to be dynamic based on server account (set without actually "knowing" it to the server default of accountname@host.servername.com) So far this is not possible without some fancy parting out of hostname etc. Might go that right. Thanks again.